# casperJS failed Injecting jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, phantomjs, casperjs

Does anyone know how come I am encountering

```
[warning] [phantom] Failed injecting %s client side. 
Failed injecting includes/jquery-1.10.2.min.js client side
```

when I have included

```
'includes/jquery-1.10.2.min.js'
```

within the Casper constructor. Someone posted a similar question here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/casperjs/hY4ziaoXIEE/YFi8Sj4JysMJ, but I do not understand how they have incorporated the casper.evaluate() in their solution:

```
casper.then( function() {
this.evaluate(function($) {
console.log($('title').text());
}
});
```

Comment: Maybe you didn't copy and paste your code, but,  you're missing a closing `)` for the .evaluate()` function.

Comment: That question is saying it couldn't find the script, it's probably a path problem

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't remember ever being able to inject scripts using the clientScripts option of the CasperJs constructor. Instead I have found the following works for me always.

```
casper = require('casper').create();
casper.start();
casper.open('some url');
casper.then(function doSomething() {
    this.page.injectJs('relative/local/path/to/jquery.js');
    var items = this.evaluate(function () {
        return $('div.someClass'); // jquery here
    });
});
```

Comment: The example the OP linked to shows the other way of including it

Comment: @JuanMendes, I doubt it. http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#evaluate shows that you need to explicitly specify the values that are to be passed to the function to be evaluated. The linked example's function accepts a `$` argument, but no value is specified for this `$` argument.

Comment: Yeah, but that is another issue; it is still _the_ another way of injecting scripts.

Answer (score 2):

What tripped me up was that the path to the include is relative to the directory you are **calling the script from**, NOT the directory the script actually resides in.