# CasperJS doesn't evaluate jQuery method

Tags: javascript, jquery, testing, casperjs

I injected jQuery to CasperJS:

```
phantom.injectJs('./utils/jquery/jquery-2.1.4.js');
```

but when I try to evaluate some jQuery code, it is ignored:
example:

```
function dragNdropAlertToActivity() {
    var tt = casper.evaluate(function() {
        $('div[id^="scheduler-alert-grid"] table:contains(BLUE ALERT)')[0].simulate("drag-n-drop", {
            dragTarget: {
                dx: 71,
                dy: 71,
                interpolation: {
                    stepCount: 2
                }
            }
        });
        return "done";
    });
    casper.echo(tt);
};
```

calling method like: `casper.test.begin(function(){...})`.
test are executed using: `casperjs test tests`

The output says that `$` cannot be found.

Why does it ignore jQuery, when I write even a simple selector?

Comment: Looks fine. What's the output of your script? Please register to the `resource.error`, `page.error`, `remote.message` and `casper.page.onResourceTimeout` events ([Example](https://gist.github.com/artjomb/4cf43d16ce50d8674fdf)). Maybe there are errors.

Comment: it cannot find variable `$`, should I pass it additionaly somehow ?

Comment: Why not using `casper.options.clientScripts`?

Comment: it says me attempt to access read only variable, if I use 'casper.options.clientScript'

Answer (score 1):

The [`phantom.injectJs()`](http://phantomjs.org/api/phantom/method/inject-js.html) documentation clearly says (emphasis mine):

> Injects external script code from the specified file into the Phantom ***outer*** space.

Which means that jQuery is not injected into the page context where you try to use it.

You can either use the manual approach ([ref](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17901812)):

```
casper.then(function doSomething() {
    this.page.injectJs('relative/local/path/to/jquery.js');
    var tt = this.evaluate(function () {
        // ...
    });
});
```

or the normal CasperJS approach which injects the script on every page that you visit:

```
var casper = require("casper").create({
    clientScripts: ["relative/local/path/to/jquery.js"]
});
```

or

```
casper.options.clientScripts.push("relative/local/path/to/jquery.js");
```