# Get text from a txt file in the url

Tags: javascript, html, http

When  I go to a url like this: http ://my.url.com/file.txt, the browser shows text.

I would like a simple javscript command that does the following:
 1. go to the url
 3. take the text that shows up on the screen
 4. store it in a variable for further processing

so something like

```
var url = http: //my.url.com/file.txt;
```

//some code here that goes to the url

//some code that takes said info and does something like:

```
var fileInfo = ---content of file.txt---
```

Note that the info I seek from the txt file is in html tags

```
<p>Text I need in Variable</p>
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTTP GET request in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/247483/http-get-request-in-javascript)

Comment: or you could use PHP http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/a/8567146/5053667

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I load the contents of a text file into a javascript variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/196498/how-do-i-load-the-contents-of-a-text-file-into-a-javascript-variable)

Answer (score 14):

## [**Use the Fetch API.**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)

[**Play with it**](https://jsfiddle.net/ynnLk5qw/1/) at [jsfiddle.net.](http://jsfiddle.net)

```js
var url = 'https://fiddle.jshell.net/robots.txt';
var storedText;

fetch(url)
  .then(function(response) {
    response.text().then(function(text) {
      storedText = text;
      done();
    });
  });

function done() {
  document.getElementById('log').textContent =
    "Here's what I got! \n" + storedText;
}
```

Here's a smaller ES6 example that separates fetching from storing and showing off the result.

```js
fetch('https://fiddle.jshell.net/robots.txt')
  .then((response) => response.text().then(yourCallback));

function yourCallback( retrievedText ) { /* . . . */ }
```

[Adoption is already across the board.](http://caniuse.com/#feat=fetch)

You don't have to wait. Most people don't. You shouldn't.
[GitHub provides a polyfill of those who can't upgrade.](https://github.com/github/fetch)

What's better about fetch than XHR? ... [Lots](https://blogs.windows.com/msedgedev/2016/05/24/fetch-and-xhr-limitations/).

Comment: Disclaimer: _Fetch support is at a fairly early stage, but progress is being made. It is turned on by default in Firefox 39 and above, and Chrome 42 and above._

Comment: For older browsers or people that refuse to update; https://github.github.io/fetch/

Comment: Thank you very much for your response, but this is the error I am getting when running this in a blank console:  
Fetch API cannot load http:// www.my-sample-url.com/file.txt. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'chrome://newtab' is therefore not allowed access. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
undefined:1 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch(…)

Comment: You're fetching from a modification to `chrome://newtab`? And you're trying to fetch an external resource... Hm. Try creating a [Request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request) instead of using the URL as a string parameter to fetch. Specify the [`.mode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request/mode) as `'no-cors'`. In this state, it may not be possible to retrieve the text. You may need to ask this as a different question concerning chrome://newtab specifically.

Comment: Excellent example. I just made a bare-bones static site handler (didn't want all the overhead of a 'real' SSG) that pulls in .md files using `fetch` and converts them to HTML inside my static HTML pages on the fly. Now I can just `git push` and the site is updated on GitHub pages :-)

Answer (score 6):

Make an AJAX call to the url. Here is using the [jQuery](http://jquery.com/download/) library:

```
$.get( "http: //my.url.com/file.txt", function( data ) {
  var text = data;
});
```

To extract what you need from your text string in between the paragraph tags, try regex:

```
var pText = text.match(/<p>([^<]+)<\/p>/)[1];
```

Comment: You makes assumptions: everyone use JQuery ?!

Comment: You really want to use vanilla javascript? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8567114/how-to-make-an-ajax-call-without-jquery

Comment: There's some cases where you're stuck with vanilla JS ;)

Comment: @ndcomix +1 for sassiness

Comment: If you're a CasperJS dev, you play with what the remote website use. If there's no JQuery, no cigar. It's an example

Comment: That's a bit off topic, and this is too; you could scope and inject a support library... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31566465/casperjs-doesnt-evaluate-jquery-method

Comment: JQuery's ajax support is a better solution than old xhr... they handle the gotchas for you. https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/ajax/xhr.js Check out the commit history on that one!

Answer (score 0):

Using *vanilla JS* :

From the MDN doc :

```
function reqListener () {
  console.log(this.responseText);
}

var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
oReq.addEventListener("load", reqListener);
oReq.open("GET", "http://www.example.org/example.txt");
oReq.send();
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest

Read the doc and [ndcomix SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1375710/ndcomix) to go further (error checking and such)

Comment: Since before Febuary of 2015, we've been climbing out of the dark ages. https://davidwalsh.name/fetch https://gauntface.com/blog/2015/02/11/fetch-is-the-new-xhr

Comment: Disclaimer: Not supported in all browsers. Here's a polyfill. https://github.com/LuvDaSun/xhr-polyfill

Answer (score -2):

Just use jquery. It's easy fun and extensible. Don't try bizzare uses. Be sure all the time to be compatible through all the browser. If you copy this and run it under a local or remote webserver will work like a charm.
Cheers.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $.ajax({url: "test.txt", success: function(result){
            $("#div1").html(result);
        }});
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="div1"><h2>Let jQuery AJAX Change This Text</h2></div>

<button>Get External Content</button>

</body>
</html>
```