# How to render a text file from a URL using reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

With code below, I am able to render the content of the local text file to the web page, but when I use a URL to get the text file to render it on the webpage, I get `" "` because the state is defined `null`. To render a local text file I had to use `import text from './filepath.txt`. How I can render text content from a URL link?

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import text from "./myText.txt";

class App extends Component {

state = { loading: true,
          docText: null,
    };

componentDidMount() {

        fetch( text, { mode: "no-cors" }
            // { 
            //   method: "GET",
            //   headers: {
            //     "Content-Type": "application/text",
            //   },
            // }
           ).then((response) => { return response.text();})
            .then((data) => {
            this.setState({ docText: data, loading: false });
            console.log({ docText: data });
                })
            .catch((error) => { console.log(error);
             });
      }

render() { 
    return (
         <div className="App">
     <h1>Fetched Data</h1>
         <div>
             {this.state.loading || !this.state.docText ? (
             <div>Loading...</div>
                  ) : ( 
            <div> 
            <div>{this.state.docText}</div>
            </div>
            )}
            </div>
            </div>
            );
        }
}
export default App;
```

Comment: You can use iframe for that. <iframe src={src} height={someHeight} width={someWidth}   id = "frame"  /> Here src prop value would be your URL

Answer (score 2):

Before rendering the content to the DOM, verify whether the file is read from the url.

Please try the below code,

```js
fetch("https://URL/file").then((r)=>{r.text().then(d=>console.log(d))})
```

try steps mentioned in this question [Get text from a txt file in the url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39758031/get-text-from-a-txt-file-in-the-url)

Comment: unable to see anything in console.

Comment: Please check the url, whether the data is available there or it requires some permission (like login credentials or password) to read data from the url

Comment: Data is available in the text file and it doesn't require any permission to access it. You may check the link given in the sandbox code given above.